# Can conditional breakpoints be set while debugging in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging, ssms, conditional-breakpoint

I've just begun using breakpoints to debug a T-SQL stored procedure in Management Studio (SQL Server 2008). I notice that the breakpoints window has a condition column:

[image]

But I can't find any way to actually **specify a condition** on a breakpoint, not via the Debug menu, not via a context menu on the breakpoint or within the breakpoint window, etc.

Is there a way to use conditional breakpoints in SSMS, or does that column exist for some future version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they can't. From [this site](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1695), you can see some of the other limitations also.

Here's the relevant quote:

> The T-SQL debugger does not support the Microsoft Visual Studio features of setting breakpoint conditions or hit counts.

Comment: Unfortunate! I'll have to fall back on setting breakpoints on "dummy" statements inside conditional blocks, like in the bad old VB6 days.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround:

in case my condition is `@IterationNR = 18` I have stated

`IF @IterationNR = 18
SET @IterationNR = @IterationNR`

and set breakpoint to line with `SET` command...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to create a C# or VB .NET application that uses ADO .NET to execute the SQL query that you were executing on SQL Server Management Studio, and set the conditional or hit-count breakpoint within Visual Studio on the SqlCommand object.